# Automatically sync all zones between BIND 9

Tags: bind, dns-zone

Is there a way to automatically synchronize all zones between BIND (9) servers so that I don't have to add zones to the slave when I add them to the master?

Comment: other than adding them manually to named.conf, I don't see other way; if that is what you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the amount of zones I have, syncing manually ended up being easier than getting any other solution to work. If I had many more zones I'd look into the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 15):

Look at BIND 9.7.2-P2 in which you have the "rndc addzone" and "rndc delzone" statements that allow you to "remotely" add and remove zones from a running server.

I have a paper that provides some examples that I gave at NANOG last month.

ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/pubs/pres/NANOG/50/DNSSEC-NANOG50.pdf

While this won't go back and clean up any mess that you have currently, it does make it really easy to synchronize machines that you are able to manage using "rndc" going forward.

[yes, responding to a rather old post, but BIND 9.7.2-P2 is cool enough to warrant it]

**Adding yet another update (years after the fact, but hoping that it helps folks that run across this in search results), I'd like to recommend the use of Catalog zones.**

Catalog zones, introduced in BIND 9.11 (2018) allow automatic provisioning of zones (addition and deletion) through a special zone that is shared among the primary and secondary servers.

For full information, see:  https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01401

Comment: When promoting software you're associated with please include some reference to that fact (even if the software is free). Thank you and welcome to Server Fault.

Comment: Yep, I work for ISC, the guys that maintain BIND and ISC DHCP.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any way to do this natively to bind9 if you're using flatfile backend. There are various DB-backed systems which can help automate it.  Or you can script it:

I populate a text file with a list of zones and the primary NS IP for the zone, and stick it on a website that I allow my slaves access to. The slaves fetch this file periodically, and if it has changed they parse it generate a named.conf, and tell bind to reload configs. It's "automatic" in the sense that I don't have to manually ssh to my secondaries and update configs, but it's still external to bind9.

You could also use a higher level configuration management system such as [puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet), to manage your entire DNS infrastructure. That's a bit more complicated though.

Comment: +1 - I use a similar (but probably less efficient) technique myself and it seems to work reliably. To get quick propagation to the slaves of new changes they need to poll the master document frequently (I have found every ten minutes to be more than frequent enough).

Comment: Back before I got the dual religions of Automation and Tinydns, I had a script which parsed the master's zone config list to get the list of zones, which I exposed via inetd, and then a script on the slaves which polled any number of master IP addresses (and used that address as the master IP address in their slave configs).  Worked a dream.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're looking for a configuration management system like [Puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet/) or [CFEngine?](http://www.cfengine.org/) There's extra infrastructure involved, but they can handle distributing a lot of configuration stuff, and could easily include this too.

Answer (score 2):

Bind itself can't do it. More to the point, it would be undesirable to have it do so. There are many situations where only certain domains should be replicated with any given slave.

Comment: Now BIND apparently can, see @Knobee's answer.

Comment: @mad_vs - Thanks, I wouldn't have seen that answer otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Using rsync on your entire /var/named tree works pretty well if you write your zones correctly and make sure named.conf lives in /var/named. It won't work with dynamic updates though, and is sorta against the grain for "how things should be done".

I've also experimented with stuffing all the domains to propagate into a special zone, and used a simple script on the slaves to rebuild the named.conf based on what they see in the master zone. Basically the same deal as the text file above, but feeding it from DNS to keep everything in-band. I should probably publish the script before I end up losing it =/

In the days of everybody and their mom having their own domains, it surprises me there isn't a good solution for this integrated with Bind by now =/

Answer (score 0):

I second (or third) the above suggestions to check out Puppet or CFEngine. Also, you could look at checking your files into and out of CVS/SVN. If you're interested in a scripting solution, here's what I use:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
archive='/root/dns'
cd $archive
[ $1 ] && DEBUG=$1
if [ "$DEBUG" == "-debug" ]; then 
        echo "Debugging activated..."
else
        unset DEBUG
fi

for server in dnsm02 dnsm03 dnsm51 dnsm52; do

        for file in named.conf named.cfx.conf named.external.conf named.internal.conf named.logging.conf named.options.conf; do
                PATCHDIR="$archive/$server/$DATE/patch" && [ $DEBUG ] && echo "PATCHDIR = $PATCHDIR"
                SRVDIR="$archive/$server/$DATE" && [ $DEBUG ] && echo "SRVDIR = $SRVDIR"

                ## Fetch bind config files from $server, put them in date stamped $archive/$server
                [ ! -d $PATCHDIR ] && mkdir -p $PATCHDIR  && [ $DEBUG ] && echo "Created archive directory"
                scp -q user@$server:/etc/bind/$file $archive/$server/$DATE/$file && [ $DEBUG ] && echo "Copied remote $file from $server..."

                ## diff fetched file against template file and create a patch
                [ $DEBUG ] && echo "Creating patch file..."
                diff -u $SRVDIR/$file $archive/$server/$file > $PATCHDIR/patch.$file
                [ ! -s $PATCHDIR/patch.$file ]  && rm -f $PATCHDIR/patch.$file && [ $DEBUG ] &&  echo "no differences , no patch created for $server $file"
                [ -s $PATCHDIR/patch.$file ] && patch $SRVDIR/$file $PATCHDIR/patch.$file && ssh user@$server "sudo scp user@dnsm01:$SRVDIR/$file /etc/bind/$file" && [ $DEBUG ] && echo "$file patched and uploaded"
        done
        [ $DEBUG ] && echo "Checking whether patch directory is empty..."
        [ $(ls -1A $PATCHDIR | wc -l) -eq 0 ] && rmdir $PATCHDIR && [ $DEBUG ] && echo "$PATCHDIR empty, removing..."

        ssh user@$server "sudo rndc reload"
done
```

ssh keys are pretty essential to this setup. I do not claim extraordinary scripting-fu powers, so feel free to criticize, but be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a script to rip all the zone file names from the master (ls -1 will do most of this).
2. Create a script on the slave that will take the list of zone files as input, and create a named.conf.local from that list (the formatting is pretty simple), and replace the existing named.conf.local (you can use another name, and include it from named.conf.local if you want to play it safe)
3. create a single-command passwordless sudo access for "rndc reload" on the slave.
4. Create a single-use ssh key that allows you to send the list of zones from the master, and pipe it into the slave script and then run "sudo rndc reload". You can now push the zones from the master to the slave.
5. (optional) create a cron job to push the zones daily, or what ever.

Good experience, working this out. I can post my scripts, if anyone wants them.

Comment: @naught101, can you post the scripts please?

Answer (score 0):

This is some php code that the master server can run to create a list. Options then could be to upload it to a DB or the other DNS servers can pull it over http/s.

**Master server can run this:**

```
$dir = "/var/lib/bind";
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file) {
    $zoneparts = explode(".hosts", $file);
   if(count($zoneparts) > 1){
       echo $zoneparts[0] . "\r\n";
   }
}
```

**Slave server can run this:**

```
$zones = file(URL TO MASTER SERVER);
if($zones != ""){

$header = "// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
";




file_put_contents("/var/www/html/zone/zones.txt", $header);

foreach($zones as $zone){
if($zone != "") {
$zone = preg_replace('~[[:cntrl:]]~', '', $zone);
$config = 'zone "' . $zone.'" {
        type slave;
        masters {lemming; };
        allow-transfer {none; };
        file "/var/lib/bind/db.'.$zone.'";
};

';


file_put_contents('/var/www/html/zone/zones.txt', $config, FILE_APPEND);
}}

}
```

*The "zone" dir will need to be writeable*

**Then create a bash script like this:**

```
#!/bin/bash

    php /var/www/html/index.php
    cp /var/www/html/zone/zones.txt /etc/bind/named.conf
    service bind9 restart
    logger DNS Zones pulled from master and bind restarted /home/bob/dns_sync.sh
```

**Then create a chronjob as root (crontab -e):**

```
*/10 * * * * /home/bob/dns_sync.sh
```